# Space elevator: a Earth rotation brake model

Tags: rotational-dynamics, friction

I read this article regarding the [space elevator](http://membercentral.aaas.org/blogs/scientia/space-elevator).

A very long carbon nanotubes string, running from the Earth surface into the vacuum of the space.
Tension and friction, an enormous quantity of dissipated heat, conducted by the nanotubes into energy storages. A kind of giant space mill.

But also a kind of space brake, slightly slowing down Earth's rotation, day after day.

My question is the following. Is it possible to calculate the (negative) angular acceleration generated by the space elevator friction?

**Edit**

I guess there is a not null energy amount dissipated as friction between the 'cable' and the atmosphere. And this should work as a brake.

Comment: Why would it act as a brake? The only friction mentioned in the article is between the elevator and its cable. The article says this will produce enough heat to worry about getting rid of it, but it won't slow down the Earth any more than a normal elevator in a skyscraper does.

Comment: (Though I'm not even sure the dissipation thing is that big of a worry anyway - why wouldn't you just transfer the heat to the cable and let it radiate away slowly?)

Comment: When mass is pulled up the elevator, it changes the total angular inertia of the Earth/elevator system, causing it to slow. If the mass is released at the top to fly off into space, then the slow-down is permanent. Moving mass down the elevator, on the other hand, will cause the Earth to speed up. Either way, friction has nothing to do with it. It is possible to calculate the rate of angular acceleration: it just depends on the rate of mass transfer up or down the elevator.

Comment: Energy dissipated as friction between the cable and the atmosphere is taken from energy of atmosphere that comes from solar heating, not Earth rotation.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277688/space-elevator-solved